# In regex how to split by "." and match the first block of digits?

Tags: regex, power-automate

I use regex sparingly only when it comes up in projects. I've tried to learn, but I'm stuck. Any help would be much appreciated!

#### Expected Behavior

| `FNBR6.03202021.Default_Title.mp4` | `GEVY230.03182021.Project76.mp4` |
| --- | --- |
| `FNBR` | `GEVY` |
| `6` | `230` |
| `03202021` | `03182021` |
| `Default_Title` | `Project76` |
| `mp4` | `mp4` |

Sample Array: `[FNBR, 6, 03202021, Default_Title, mp4]`

#### What I have

I have gotten this far: `/(^.+?(?=\d))|(\d+)|([^.]+)/gm`

| Expression | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `^.+?(?=\d)` | This should match everything up until a digit. |
| `(\d+)` | This should match digits in blocks (next to each other). |
| `([^.]+)` | This should match everything except `.` |

So I tried to put it together using `|` OR operator. I got a list like so `[FNBR, 6, ., 30202021, .Default_Title.mp, 4, ]`. Which I was expecting, but I don't know how to continue.

I know I need basically what `([^.]+)` does, with the exception of the first block of digits. I only care about separating the first block of digits before the first `.` decimal/period. So in `FNBR6.03202021.Default_Title.mp4` I only care about separating `FNBR6` into `FNBR` and `6`, after that everything is just split like normal using `.`

I am not using a standard programing language like Python or Java; it would be a hassle to have to do this using two regex expressions. Like splitting everything by `.` and then just splitting index[0] of  `FNBR6` separately. I don't want that.

Any help, feedback, and criticism would be much appreciated! I tried not to make this too long, but I also wanted to ensure I thoroughly explained the situation. Thanks!

### Edit 1: Helpful Suggestions

[@41686d6564](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8967612/41686d6564)  points out that I should mention what platform I'm using. I'm testing Microsoft Power Automate Desktop for work. That's what I'm running the regex expressions in.

[@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) listed a bunch of very helpful examples in the comments. However, none of them seem to work properly in this program.

Using `/(^.+?(?=\d))|(\d+)|([^.]+)/gm`:
[image: My Bad Regex output]

Using any of trincot's examples like [`[A-Z]{2,}|\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/0yqOgL/2) give:
[image: Trincot Example Output]

### Edit 2: Reliable Answer

[@knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl)'s example worked reliably and works as needed. Their deconstruction and explanation were also very helpful. Thanks!
[image: knittl working example output]
Power Automate seems to make the first and last index empty when using regular expressions to create a list. I just simply remove the first and last index.

I tried everyone's comments/suggestions in the order in which they were posted. knittl's was the first that worked reliably. I want to thank everyone for their quick, and thoughtful help! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Does [`[A-Z]{2,}|\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/0yqOgL/2) do what you want? Or else [`[A-Z]{2,}|[^.]+`](https://regex101.com/r/0yqOgL/3/)? Or even [`[A-Z]+(?=\d)|[^.]+`](https://regex101.com/r/CY48AQ/1/)?

Comment: _"I am not using a standard programing language like Python or Java"_ What are you using? It's very important to mention the language/tool/flavor when posting regex questions because not all regex flavors/engines support the same set of features.

Comment: @trincot No sadly, and...

Comment: as @41686d6564 mentions, I should explain what I'm using.

Comment: Can you please clarify the rules then? Do you have examples for which my proposals don't work as you wish, and what is the expected result in those cases?

Comment: Sorry, but your edit does not faithfully represent the regex I proposed: you escaped the square brackets, so they are interpreted as literals. Why did you do that? BTW, the link to regex101.com shows that that image of the output you have does not correspond to the output generated there.

Comment: Does your tool require that matches are in capture groups? If so, then consider [`([A-Z]+(?=\d))|([^.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/E8iFHa/1/)

Comment: @AnthonyAlphabet Did you try trincot's suggestion without escaping the square brackets? `[A-Z]{2,}|\w+` Are there always the same amount of dots in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not sound too complicated. It only becomes complicated when people start to use lookahead and lookbehinds when they are not required. With the information given, each part can be matched directly with simple character classes and quantifiers.

Input: FNBR6.03202021.Default_Title.mp4

Regex:

```
([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([^.]+)\.(.+)
```

Deconstructed:

- `([^0-9]+)` match any number of non-digits and capture in group 1 (but match at least one character)
- `([0-9]+)` match any number of digits and capture in group 2 (at least 1 digit)
- `\.` match one literal dot
- `([0-9]+)` match any number of digits and capture in group 3 (at least 1 digit)
- `\.` match one literal dot
- `([^.]+)` match any number of characters which are not the dot and capture in group 4 (at least one character)
- `\.` match one literal dot
- `(.+)` match the rest of the input and capture in group 5. Can be anything (but again: at least 1 character)

Try it online on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZJf9Hs/1).

NB. depending on your regex flavor, `[0-9]` can be shortened to `\d` and `[^0-9]` can be replaced with `\D`, resulting in: `(\D+)(\d+)\.(\d+)\.([^.]+)\.(.+)`

Or if can already split the string into an array/multiple variables, split first, then apply regex (pseudo code):

```
var allparts = input.split('.');
var firstpart = part[0].match(/^(\D+)(\d+)$/);
// firstpart[0] = FNBR
// firstpart[1] = 6
```

Comment: This answer works the most reliably, albeit with the first and last index being blank. I have accepted this answer, as it does what I need, and gave a constructive deconstruction of the regular expression.

Comment: @AnthonyAlphabet why would the first group be empty? Or what exactly do you mean with "first index is empty"? Maybe this power automate starts groups at index 1 and leaves index 0 always empty? Maybe you need to anchor your regex: `^regex$`?

Comment: If you look under my original post section "Edit 2: Reliable Answer" there is a screenshot of what I mean. At index 0 and the last index, it is empty. I'm not a big fan of this Power Automate. I just remove index 0 and len-1, it works fine. I did try anchoring using ^expresion$, but the same result. Thanks though!

Comment: After creating and adding other regular expressions it seems like Power Automate adds empty index at the beginning and end of a list when using regular expressions. It's a preview program, very buggy, and there is a chance I'm doing something wrong as Microsoft's documentation is lacking.

Comment: @AnthonyAlphabet I see. Thanks for the update!